# publish array velocities in a topic?

Tags: ros, gazebo, topic, array, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users!
I have just done a .cpp wich publish velocities in a opic (p3dx/cmd_vel)
Here it is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "lanzando_vel");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher vel_pub_ = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("p3dx/cmd_vel", 1);
  
  while (ros::ok())
  {
  geometry_msgs::Twist cmd;
  cmd.linear.x = 0;
  cmd.linear.y = 0;
  cmd.linear.z = 0;

  cmd.angular.x = 0;
  cmd.angular.y = 0;
  cmd.angular.z = 0;
    vel_pub_.publish(cmd);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to publish an array velocities, for example:

at 1seg ==> cmd.linear.x=1
at 3 seg==> cmd.linear.x=4
.
.
.

how can I do that?

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208149/publish-array-velocities-in-a-topic?/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You can create your own message Velocity array.
Then you fill your array with twist messages.
Finally you publish it.
You have an example in python [in this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/207071/how-to-fill-up-a-pointcloud-message-with-data-in-python/).

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although I haven't done it personally, I would try using [TwistStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistStamped.html), put its instances into an array (as @marguedas does in the link provided), particularly when you want to specify the timing where the Twist gets executed. You can specify it in its `header.stamp`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1